# how to localize today extensions widget?

Tags: ios, ios8, widget, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

Our application has support for multiple region and languages. When I develop today extensions widget and read [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1), I still can't find a localize solution. Even if I created the Localize.strings file like a normal Xcode project, define Localize.strings file like:

```
"scene_people_liked"="%d people like";
```

use :

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
            [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:moLocalizedPath] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:@"Localizable"]
```

and call it with:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"scene_people_liked", nil)
```

, it still does't work. Anyone has an idea about this problem?

Comment: Is the strings file included in the extension bundle, or just the app?

Comment: just stay the app,need included to today widget?

Comment: @TomHarrington included in the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take some time i has been resolved this problem.
if you want localize your today extensions widget, actually it was does't have any different step with do it in a normal project.

but it has litter problem about "Localize.strings" file name, you must have use "Localize" to named "Localize.strings" file in the normal project。localize should be work,but if you use it same name as main application or use some "InfoPlist.String" keyword,

even if test everything fine when you debug your project ,but when you package it up and install device, you will find out the localize can't get the value, so you must define a customer name without "Localize.strings" or some keywords.

:)

Comment: This shouldn't be the approved answer for a number of evident reasons.

Answer (score 15):

Check that your TodayWidget target has the Localizable.strings files in the target membership.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thanks @rockdaswift